# Why can't I delete my posts?

Tags: support

It won't let me delete my own post. I wanted to delete it because it was a "duplicate" as some ignorant person claimed yet it wasn't because I was asking a different question.

I could only delete it by reporting it which I did twice and they didn't delete it.

I edited my post asking for it to be deleted and they still didn't delete it.

And on top of that, everyone is down-voting it for no reason (even when I posted the question)

The link is here: [Synchronization - Difference between locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174354/synchronized-block-method-and-volatile-issue)

I thought this site was not as stupid as it seemed but considering I can't delete my own questions that apparently everyone hates, I'm really not feeling up to dealing with this crap.

They said it was a duplicate of this: [Is there an advantage to use a Synchronized Method instead of a Synchronized Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method)

Which it wasn't. I wasn't asking what is the difference between blatantly a synchronized block and synchronized method. I was asking what is the difference between locking onto an instance of the class, locking on the method itself, and locking on the instance of the variable I am using in the method.

Comment: It has an answer that has a score of 1 or more. It is also locked by a moderator.

Comment: I selected an answer because I was annoyed by getting down-voted. The moderator locked it just so I can't edit or try deleting it.

Comment: Lol, I'm done with this website. Everyone just loves down-voting, don't they?

Comment: well, calling the people who might issue down votes "ignorant" probably doesnt help matters.

Comment: It is block level synchronization and method level synchronization difference. Looks like a valid duplicate. Did you understand the concept? The primary motive is to help you with a solution. So, if you are unable to understand, then please mention _what didn't you understand_.

Comment: The post is locked now and no one can vote on it. Also, no one can edit it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't delete it in the usual way (via a delete vote) because it has an upvoted answer.

You can't vandalize it, because we don't allow that.

In general, duplicate stubs are good; they help people searching in Google to find the original post.  Your question received an answer with three votes.  It's not exactly fair to that guy to have to lose his earned rep when your question is deleted.

Not for nothing, but I think some of those downvotes on your question occurred because you tried to vandalize your question.  The community really does not like that.

Comment: You do that by casting a custom moderator flag, and providing an explanation why you think the post should be deleted.

Comment: It never said anything about using custom instead of the default choices.

Comment: What default choices?  There isn't any bullet for "This is my post, it's a duplicate, and I'm getting tired of being downvoted.  Can you please delete it?"

Answer (score 7):

You can't delete it because it has an upvoted answer.

It was locked because you kept vandalising the post.

Moderators will not necessarily delete a question for you which is why your flags were declined. You have to have a really good reason for wanting the question deleted.

If you are so sure that your question is not a duplicate then edit it to make that fact clear. It will then be automatically added to the reopen review queue from where, if enough other users agree, it will be reopened.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting a post after someone has taken the time to answer it for you is considered kind of rude. Your question was closed as a duplicate because as it is written it does seem to be answered already by an older question. It was probably downvoted because you don't seem to have put in a lot of effort in researching the question to begin with, then you vandalized it after it was closed.

I've unlocked the question now. Please edit it to make clear what you are asking is different from the older question.

Comment: There is no point in that. Everyone down-voted it regardless and it's "marked as duplicate".

Comment: @Sparta "marked as duplicate" is not carved in stone.

Comment: Okay I edited it.

Comment: @Sparta http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773