# I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, deleted-questions, homework

I asked a question related to a course I was taking. I followed all the Stack Overflow rules, and I got a useful answer. But it's coming to the end of the [grading period here], and my professor has warned us that anyone who tried to get outside help with our coursework will be [punished/expelled].

I realize now it was a mistake to ask that on Stack Overflow, and I want to get my question deleted. I tried to delete my question but learned [I can't delete it if it has an upvoted/accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268037) (or I deleted the question after I got an answer but [someone undeleted it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118)). I tried to edit it out, but the edit was reverted and a moderator locked my post!

I don't have time for any strategy other than deletion because they will be checking soon and they might find my question and punish me!

Please, I'm sorry! I just want my question deleted! Why won't anyone help me?

> <sup>**Note:** This is a FAQ entry for a specific type of flag that we commonly field. While this issue is covered extensively in a lot of other questions, it's helpful to point people to one Meta post when declining these flags.</sup>

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225)

Comment: Why can't you change the name of your account so they don't find you? How are they doing the search? What's the guarantee that they'll find the post in any case?

Comment: "Getting outside help" usually means getting someone else to do your work. There are many websites where freelancers offer their services to complete homework assignments. Getting your homework done through freelancers or friends or a family members without you actually doing work and learning, is what the teachers are against. Asking a question on StackOverflow to resolve a doubt is a totally different situation. Getting a doubt cleared on StackOverflow is like asking a senior or a teacher for knowledge. It is not plagiarism or illegal in any way. You've probably got nothing to worry about.

Comment: I almost believed this to be a true story

Comment: It is a true story, @Rainb; it's just not autobiographical. :-)

Comment: Just the thoughts of a university lecturer here: you can disconnect your name from the account in some way, but if you've effectively copied a solution someone gave you, then there is a good chance that the solution is identifiable on your submission.  As a general rule for getting help on assignments - don't copy.  It's probably fine to get help understanding the problem.  It's not fine to submit a solution you don't understand.

Comment: In real life, you'll often ask questions (and answer questions) in stackex and other forums. If the university forbids this, then the root cause of the problem are the university rules, not asking questions. This would be similar to forbidding students to check books or journals. If this rule exist in your university, you should attempt to change the rules instead of deleting your question. In a professional setting, I prefer a colleague that knows how to ask in stack rather than someone who just memorized a textbook to get the degree.

Comment: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 87, accepted):

We intentionally make it difficult to delete questions, as that ultimately subverts our mission. As [noted by Shog9, a former community manager](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909):

> We're trying to create a library of reusable information here, with the idea that if someone takes the time to define their problem and then search for it they won't have to ask a question at all! When it works, any answer can go on to benefit many people beyond the person who asked the question...

We also need to be fair to the people who took time to help you. As explained in the Help Center article, ["I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question):

> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

Those two reasons alone make up about 99% of the basis for our policy restricting self-deletion of questions. Someone took the time to help you. They shouldn't be penalized for your mistake. But there's a far larger problem you're facing, namely:

### The Internet doesn't forget easily

Search engines crawl/spider Stack Overflow very aggressively. In many cases, questions are picked up by Google less than 30 minutes after posting and can survive in search results long after the question is deleted. There are also "scraper" sites that might pick it up as well and repost it as you posted it. Your question is virtually guaranteed to hang around in some form or another on the Internet, whether you delete or dissociate it.

### But I'll be failed or expelled if it's not deleted NOW!

Maybe. You might want to have an open talk with your professors about this (especially before they start looking and find the evidence themselves). It's possible that things can be salvaged. There are legitimate ways to ask for help that do not constitute outright cheating. But, ultimately, you should understand that your college/university has to uphold their integrity. As [one tutor complained upon finding evidence of cheating on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295420):

> I care about the academic integrity of our program; finding misconduct is my full time job. If you are going to cheat, it's pretty much you versus me.

Think about it: you're trying to get a piece of paper that meaningfully says you met their criteria for graduation (*i.e.*, a degree). If you get away with this, how many others have as well? It diminishes the value of your degree. You should also consider that you're really cheating yourself by posting homework here. As noted in [Software Engineering's "open letter to students with homework problems"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems):

> Copy and paste takes no skill. It cheats you out of the education you are paying to get.
>
> It cheats us of good interview candidates. Technical interviewers often complain about the quality of college graduates. You may be enthusiastic, but unless you can write code and explain concepts better than the other person, we're going to hire the other person.

### TL;DR: I can't get it deleted?

In most cases, no. There is no fast solution here, let alone one that will keep the evidence hidden. **Moderators will not assist you in covering up evidence of academic dishonesty. The only basis on which we will delete questions is the value they provide to *this site*.**

Additionally:

- *Deleting a post does not permanently banish it from the site!* As the help center says:

  > Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted questions and answers are always visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation.

  So in case the teacher is secretly a 10K user on Stack Overflow...
- Someone else with 10K privilege might tell the teacher or show them a screenshot of your post.
- Don't think you're in the clear if you manage to delete your answered question before the system measures to prevent it kick in. This is a [violation of site policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118/2157772) if the answer was valuable; your question will be undeleted and possibly locked, and you may be suspended from the site.

If you still have questions, please be sure you have [read the Help Center on deletion alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) first before flagging.

Answer (score 21):

If you are worried about being expelled for asking for outside help, here is some advice:

1. Don't do it.
2. If you've already asked for help, don't submit your assignment.  You will get zero marks, but there should be<sup>1</sup> no other (disciplinary) consequences.
3. If you have already submitted your assignment, ask if you can **withdraw** the submission.  This one is more tenuous, and you may still get a penalty ... depending on your teacher and school's policy.  (Note that you will probably need to say *why* you are asking to withdraw the submission, and you would be well advised to be truthful ... 'cos they are not idiots.)

---

As for getting Stack Overflow moderators to delete your question so that you won't be caught cheating… I doubt that would happen.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I don't know what your school's policy is on this, and I/we have no basis to know how they would view this, but I think it would be a bit unjust for you to be penalized for cheating for this.  In my opinion, it is not cheating if you ask for help, but then don't submit your assignment.</sup>

Comment: The suggestion not to submit the assignment after you've asked for help, potentially committing scholastic dishonesty, is a very good one. This might actually be useful to people who developed a conscience after the fact and are genuinely looking for options.

Answer (score -6):

I am surprised it hasn't been mentioned here (it has on [similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185669/796931)), but you can **ask for your question to be unlinked from your account**. You can do this by flagging it for moderator attention and specifically asking for it to be unlinked from your account.

While your question may still be found by your professor, it will be more difficult for them to trace it back to you. Your professor may still be able to use third-party Internet archival sites, but that is outside of Stack Overflow's control.

Stack Overflow users get very defensive when there is mention of deleting questions, as it damages the site when questions (which other users may rely on) are removed.

However most attempts to delete a question simply want to disavow responsibility for the question. There are even laws in many countries mandating the deletion of certain personally identifiable content upon request (see [right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten)).

EDIT: [Jeanne Dark commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete#comment815452_403876) with this useful link for help with unlinking (dissociating) a question for your account:  [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa) .

Comment: It's mentioned in passing in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403803/11682469) (emphasis mine): "Your question is virtually guaranteed to hang around in some form or another on the Internet, whether you delete or *dissociate it*." Relevant is also [What is the proper route for a dissociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/11682469)

Comment: I think it would be a waste of time to flag the question under discussion.  As @Machavity (mod) said: *"Moderators will not assist you in covering up evidence of academic dishonesty.  The only basis on which we will delete questions is the value they provide to this site."*

Comment: @StephenC Unlinking is different from deleting. Moderators usually oblige(if not required) in unlinking.

Comment: @TheMaster - I quoted a mod as saying (unequivocally!) that they will not assist someone to do that.  I won't speak for them ... but if it was me, I wouldn't assist with a coverup *as a matter of principle*.  The fact that it might be easy or hard to assist would not be relevant ... to me.

Comment: @StephenC  At the end of the day, your  or any other mod's opinions on morality or ethics doesn't matter, as far as deassociation request is concerned. The license that the OP provided for the question, explicitly requires that you/mod on behalf of SO(licensee) comply with the de-association request from the licensor. https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-can-i-do-if-i-offer-my-material-under-a-creative-commons-license-and-i-do-not-like-the-way-someone-uses-it PS: I believe Machavity was only saying that specifically for the deletion request.

Comment: I think you will find that the moderators are (in fact) moral human beings and not robots.  If some prick started throwing their weight around and shouting "policy" so that they could hide evidence of their misconduct, then I would not be surprised if the request got slow-walked.

Comment: If moderators are expected to show bias for their own personal morals, It's prudent to not mention any explicit reason for the request. Even if they aren't expected to show bias, there's no need to show or provide any reason for the request. As the owner/licensor, you have a unilateral right to exercise your right to de-associate any content. If request gets delayed, you can escalate the issue to the company using their contact form(which usually gets dealt relatively fast). It's also wise to never admit any guilt in any messages to anyone, including moderators.