# Why this user can find Stack Overflow can be VERY frustrating

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, moderation

I'll probably get criticized for this too, but way too often instead of getting help on Stack Overflow, I get edited unnecessarily such as changing some bullet points to remove the bullets or changing SQLServer to SQL Server or Domain Controller to Domain controller.

It's a waste of time for me to go through and make sure the editor didn't miss something important which just happened when a large bunch of edits were made on a very detailed question and the editor accidentally deleted a very important piece of the issue.

Then the question got closed as off topic even though there are dozens to hundreds of questions that are very similar that are not closed. If all that energy went to actually helping instead of frustrating users it would be a lot friendlier place.

Also it would be nice for reputation on one of the Stack Exchange sites and to carry over to the other sites instead of having to build a whole new reputation. It is not encouraging to get treated like a noob every time you go to a new site.

I know Stack Exchange sites are very successful, so I'm sure these things have been thought through, but for this user it makes it the second or third or forth priority site I go to in order to ask a question.

Comment: A note; the existence of questions which break the rules does not mean that your post(s), which breaks the rules, is(are) allowed.  If you see a question slip through the cracks, the correct course of action is not to use it as justification for your own, but to flag it to be closed appropriately(if you don't have the vote to close ability).

Comment: Second note: Your idea of 'reputation carry over' is already, technically, a thing; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: *"I get edited unnecessarily such as changing ... changing SQLServer to SQL Server"* because we're correcting your spelling, that's not unnecessary, it's just correcting your errors. If you don't want people to correct such things, then spell Stack Overflow, SQL Server, Stack Exchange, etc, correctly in the first place. There's a simple way to help you achieve that; install a spell checker.

Comment: Presumably you're asking about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043866/one-of-2-domain-servers-went-down-and-now-i-cant-connect-to-sql-server-on-the-o); that is not on topic here as it's not about programming. More likely [DBA.se] or [SF] would be better sites (read their tours first to see which is best suited)

Comment: Thank you Daedalus.  I'll have to look for that reputation bonus.  It wasn't the existence of a question that slips through the cracks is one thing.  Dozens and dozens of questions that are about connecting to sql server for instance which was my question looks far more like someone being overly restrictive on mine rather than me trying to justify myself

Comment: @billpennock Dozens and dozens do slip through the cracks. If you see them, flag them.

Comment: The thing is you aren't asking about connecting to SQL Server, you're asking about why you can't connect to it after a domain controller failed; the cause is almost certainly the network/domain controller. Questions that are on topic here are when someone is writing an application that is trying to connect to SQL and failing; though often these do end up being closed as duplicates. There is no application or code involved here, the problem is working out why there is no network path being found between the 2 hosts after the domain controller failed.

Comment: Microsoft marketing hasn't made easier, including "server" in the product names: Running [SQL Server](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#SQL_Server) on a server with [Windows Server](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Windows_Server) installed.

Comment: @larnu: thank you. That was the most informative explanation I’ve gotten.

Answer (score 14):

Editing is one of the major ways we can help a new contributor. We strongly recommend editing any post that you think you can improve while keeping the original meaning intact. It's worth pointing out that while you are the original author and you retain the rights to the original content, the post belongs to Stack Overflow. As the site is a collaborative effort, everyone is free to edit any post they like and you cannot prevent anyone from editing it.

Stack Overflow is a questions and answers site with the aim to serve solutions to common programming problems. It is not a help desk, so you cannot expect "help" in a manner of someone assiting you with your problem. We do not offer this kind of help. This site helps by offering solutions written by experienced developers. Your question got closed because it didn't help the site achieve its goal. The question was not about a programming issue, so even if some developer answered it, it would't be of use to this site. Perhaps another site could use a question like this.

Comment: *Do* posts belong to [so]? If content on [so] is plagiarised elsewhere, it isn't [so] that handles getting it removed, it's the author of the post as they own the copyright of it, not [so].

Comment: @Larnu IANAL but it says so right here https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing

Comment: That says that "Subscriber Content" is licenced to SO, @Dharman, not owned by them (I too, am not a lawyer). My understanding is that ownership and licencing are not the same. I, as a contributor, still own my posts, however, as part of the ToS I grant SO an indefinite licence to that content. That doesnt change the fact that I own that content; if I didn't then when/if I were to use that content else where I would have to cite my post. As the owner, I don't need to do that as I own the copyright.

Comment: See this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/397219) for confirmation of my interpretation; it explicitly states that for copied content (such as from posts) *"we [Stack Overflow] do not own the content ourselves"*.

Comment: @Larnu I think we could argue about this a lot. I agree that Stack Overflow cannot claim ownership of the content. But a post does belong to the site. For example, if I were to buy an expensive work of art, I cannot claim this is my work, but I own it in my possession. The artist cannot come to my house and demand it back, make changes or deface it.

Comment: Then I simply can't agree with this post, as it claims that the content isn't owned by me, and I strongly disagree with that.

Comment: @Larnu No, you misread. You own the content, but the site owns the post.

Comment: I don't see a distinction there, @Dharman .

Comment: @Larnu :) Edvard Munch painted a famous painting called "The Scream". It exists in at least 4 copies. Some of them are currently "owned" by Munch Museum. One of them was bought by Leon Black for $120 mil. Who owns the painting?

Comment: In SEDE's `Posts` table, the column for the author is called "`OwnerUserId`". Not that that really decides anything, but I thought it to be worth noting.

Comment: A post on [so] and a painting aren't really comparable here in my opinion, @Dharman . One is work that can be easily copied and cited, the other isn't. The contents of a book would be more comparable and who the owner is; the author or the distributor of said book. That, of course, depends on the licence/contract between those 2 entities

Comment: @Larnu think of it this way, when someone defaces posts they have authored, such edits are rolled back because the post is owned by Stack Overflow, allowing the community to edit the post regardless of what the author wishes. What the author does own is the _content_ of the post, so when we make edits the edit history acts as the appropriate citation to show that it is a derivative of their content fulfilling the requirements for the licence.

Answer (score 7):

We like posts to be as high quality as possible so editing them to correct spelling and grammar issues is encouraged. Most people welcome this but in the unlikely event that an edit has made the post less readable or removed critical information you (as the post author) can rollback edits to your questions. Even then it may be better just to add back the critical section rather than throw the baby out with the bath water.

Some off-topic questions slip through the cracks. We'll close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593718/ssms-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-2017-express-on-azure-vm-using-ssms-on-lo) now that you've pointed it out to us. If I'm being honest lots and lots of questions slip through, so many people ask questions and far fewer review them.

The [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) is the feature that guarantees you 100 rep on all sites once you reach 200 on one of them.

Comment: I must admit, I don't agree with the suggestion that *useful* edits should be rolled back; that's more likely to end up with a moderator asking the OP to stop rolling back *good* contributions.

Comment: If an edit changed writing style, the author can roll back, but if an edit was made to improve readability or align with site's guidelines then **please do not roll it back**. This could result in mod intervention and the post getting locked.

Comment: @Larnu I didn't mean my answer to be read that way. I've clarified it since it was.

Answer (score 7):

> way too often instead of getting help on Stack Overflow, I get edited unnecessarily such as changing some bullet points to remove the bullets or changing SQLServer to SQL Server or Domain Controller to Domain controller.

Hello and welcome. It appears that you have a fundamental misconception about the design and intended operation of the site. It's one that almost every new user has, no matter what we try to put on the Meta site to explain it. This is partly because the staff (who actually run the company and own the site) interfere with that intent, but it's mostly because the underlying **expectation** is so strong that people seem unable to hear the message.

So, once again, I will say it loudly:

### Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.

Consequences of this include:

1. The purpose of questions on Stack Overflow *is not* to explain the trouble that the OP is currently in, and the purpose of answers *is not* to help OP out of that situation. Instead, the purpose of questions on Stack Overflow is to **describe a specific, atomic task or unexpected code behaviour**, in order to prompt an explanation.

- We do not ask:

  - [where the bug is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787) in a large piece of code;
  - [what some code dump means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894);
  - [how to complete tasks that were assigned to us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822);
  - [for tutorials](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413152);
  - [for documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592);
  - [for opinions e.g. about code style](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask);
  - [for non-specific "help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).
- We do ask:

  - how to do specific, well defined tasks, with a clear input and output specification, which don't clearly break down into simpler logical steps;
  - why specific, [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code give the result they do, rather than what OP expected.

2. Questions **are free for the site's use, not the author's exclusive property**. When you post on Stack Overflow, you [grant the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) a CC BY-SA license to your content. Of course, you maintain copyright over the work and may, for example, duplicate it on your blog; but you have no more say than anyone else in how it is edited or presented, and [may not vandalize](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/) it. The comments and answers below your question *are not* "a thread", and they *especially are not* "your thread".
3. Answers and comments are distinct because answers represent a **formal attempt to answer the actual question**, which [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that there **is a suitable question**. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, and the capital Q and capital A are the key points - they're the content we're trying to publish, and what we're hoping will be seen when someone puts something like `site:stackoverflow.com how do i foo the bar in mylang` into a search engine.
4. We have very high standards for question editing because we are **publishing** that content specifically with an eye towards **attracting as much attention as possible from search engines**, especially for the questions that are most commonly asked (or at least, most commonly are at the root of others' programming difficulties). We want to look our best.
5. We have [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569), **except for** closing bad questions [before others who Don't Get It can undermine how the site works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302). (This is one of those things where I blame the staff, because they designed a system where questions have to be closed to keep answers out, rather than one where they have to be opened to acknowledge that they meet quality standards.)

We *absolutely do want to help you*. Very often, we do help people - millions of them, constantly, judging by the site stats. However, the *primary* way that we do this is by **already having** the appropriate Q&A in place. If you must ask a question, think of it like a *bug report against the site*: implicitly, you tell us "this question is missing".

Comment: Not a new user though, they've been a member for 7+ years. That just goes to show that how new you are to the site has nothing to do with it, it is entirely rooted in your willingness to read the documentation before you start hitting buttons.